# What's the cause of the lag when I try to copy 200 GB of file?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, filesystems, file-transfer

Why is my computer lagging everytime I try to simply  copy (or move to another disk which I think is the same as copying anyway) 200 GB of file from my C:\ drive to the E:\ drive (external hard disk) ?

I mean I opened the Task Manager and

Going to `process` it shows `explorer.exe - 14k`. Doesn't look like a big problem with Ram. But I noticed that everytime I try to copy files like 200 GB my computer will be laggy.

What's the cause of the lag here?

(Windows Vista Home Premium sp2)

Comment: Can you please provide your external HDD specs, and your internal HDD specs

Comment: I'll take a stab at your virus protection scanning the file before it lets it copy.  Try disabling virus protection temporarily and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @wizlog i'm using this external: http://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-Elements-Portable-External/dp/B003B8PPEY

Comment: @wizlog i don't know how to get the internal HDD specs do you mean this: `500GB HDD` `DVD-Super Multi DL` `802.11a/b/g/Draft-N 3x3 WLAN` `4GB DDR3`

Comment: @Hand i don't have any virus protection installed and i have  firewall and defender permanently off.

Comment: Is it laggy in that applications take a long time to load, or is it laggy in that interacting with applications is very slow?

Comment: @studiohack, reopen this question.  This was closed by mistake, as Pacerier stated.  I apologize for this confusion.

Comment: @Pacerier I tried finding your drives specs... and couldn't.  Very odd...

Comment: @Hand in the sense that i can type faster than it shows on screen

Comment: @wizlog ok this is the last number I have: `Core 2 Duo processor T9950 (2.66 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB, 6 MB L2 Cache)`, `4GB DDR3`, `HDMI Out`

Comment: First read my answer's edit. Now...I think thats your processor.  I [asked](http://superuser.com/q/330752/81403) how to find the HDD cache size, and you can you HD Tune Pro. In the [Info] section, there is a cache size. It's not a free software, but it has free-trial, which should be enough in this case. The newest version also contains a cache test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the HDD's cache or buffer isn't that large, and/or that the drives need to be defragmented.

I would recomend splitting the files your trying to copy, using [Winrar](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html) or [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/).

I would also close all other programs that read/write lots of data, ex. compression software, video editing software...

You can also try to use software called [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php).  Its faster, and it can pause (in case you need to use your computer lag free in the meantime.

Comment: I never said to click format or anything...

Answer (score 5):

> Everytime I try to copy files like 200 GB my computer will be laggy

The hard disk is the *slowest* part of most any computer system, and you just told yours to spend the next several minutes (or longer) copying a very large file.  The result is taking the biggest bottleneck to system performance and making it even worse.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the system that it's ok to take 2 times longer to do the transfer but use half the resources so it doesn't bog down my computer?

Comment: @Joel, copying from the hard disk shouldn't slow down the Explorer GUI.  That's a background process to my knowledge.

Comment: @Hand - "background process" just means it plays nice with the cpu. It's still easy for this kind of thing to peg your disk i/o.

Comment: @Joel, I get that, but why would Disk IO interrupt the GUI?  Unless there's a lot of paging going on, I'd have thought the Disk IO would have so much down time that other processes would have plenty of CPU time available.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn isn't the computer supposed to be smart about it and not use 100% of it's power doing the copy?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem with my external HDD. When I tried to copy/move the files like 20-50 GB I got just 15-18 Mb/s transfer speed and system also so slow.  I thought it is my system fault but whenever I copy/move on the internal HDD it was giving me the best performance with 25-30 Mb/s transfer speed.

I checked my external HDD on friends system and the same problem was there too then I took the backup of my data which was on external HDD and delete all the partitions have on it and recreated them using Easeus Partition manager. And this wass a miracle my laptop is giving fine performance with 25-32 Mb/s transfer speed on my External HDD.

So lets take a try with backup your external HDD data and then delete the partition and Recreate them.

Comment: I don't understand with the partition part. I've not modified it since I've bought it so it's basically not partitioned? or do you mean I should do a format?

Comment: Yes I mean that. If you have not partitioned it its depend on your use. I just suggest you to do so. And delete the E: partition(if it is only available partition on your external HDD) and recreate it.