# How do I find out Hard Disk Cache / Buffer Size?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cache

How do I find out Hard Disk Cache / Buffer Size ?

Comment: What is your operating system? The simplest way would be to find the device's model using the appropriate tools and then search the manufacturer's website for specifications.

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find HDD cache size?](https://superuser.com/questions/330752/how-to-find-hdd-cache-size)

Answer (score 6):

To find your hard drive's model number:

### Method 1:

1. Open the **Device Manager** in the Control Panel or **Run** `devmgmt.msc`.
2. Under `Disk drives` you will see your hard drive's model number.
3. Enter this information into your favorite search engine.
4. Find the specifications on the manufacturer's website or from a seller.

### Method 2:

1. **Run** `msinfo32` to open **System Information**
2. Your hard drive's model will be under `Components\Storage\Disks`
3. *See #3 above*...

Comment: any offline method ?

Answer (score 1):

Seagate actually has an answer to this question in their FAQ at http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/203631en

The short version is that there is currently no way for a software to directly poll that information from a modern hard drive. Old version of the ATA specification (i.e. versions prior to the 1997 release) had a command to obtain that from the drive, but the 1997 specs made that command obsolete.

Even if modern disks were to still honor the old command, the largest value it could report would be 0xFFFF times 512 bytes, i.e. just shy of 32MB. With many hard drives now having cache size of 64 or 128MB, it just no longer works.

Finding the information from the manufacturer's spec sheet, as iglvzx stated, seems to be the only way.